# Xamarin.Forms: Tabbed page's ViewModel not getting called using Autofac

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, autofac

I am using [Autofac](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/) version 4.9.2 in my application. Following is the navigation sequence:

```
SplashView->LoginView->MainView
```

MainView is the tabbed page containing 4 tab menu. On tap of each menu item respective page is getting called but it's ViewModel is not called.

I have registered the each ViewModel class in Locator class and also added the mapping of each ViewModel with respect to it's View.

**Locator class**

```
public class Locator
{
    IContainer container;
    ContainerBuilder containerBuilder;

    public static Locator Instance { get; } = new Locator();

    public Locator()
    {
        containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        containerBuilder.RegisterType<NavigationService>().As<INavigationService>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<RequestService>().As<IRequestService>();


        containerBuilder.RegisterType<SplashViewModel>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<LoginViewModel>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<Tab1ViewModel>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<Tab2ViewModel>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<Tab3ViewModel>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<Tab4ViewModel>();

    }

    public T Resolve<T>() => container.Resolve<T>();

    public object Resolve(Type type) => container.Resolve(type);

    public void Register<TInterface, TImplementation>() where TImplementation : TInterface => containerBuilder.RegisterType<TImplementation>().As<TInterface>();

    public void Register<T>() where T : class => containerBuilder.RegisterType<T>();

    public void Build() => container = containerBuilder.Build();

}
```

**NavigationService class:**

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    readonly IAuthenticationService authenticationService;
    protected readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> mappings;

    protected Application CurrentApplication => Application.Current;

    public NavigationService()
    {
        mappings = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
        CreatePageViewModelMappings();
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await NavigateToAsync<LoginViewModel>();
    }

    public async Task NavigateBackAsync()
    {
        if (CurrentApplication.MainPage is MainView)
        {
            var mainPage = CurrentApplication.MainPage as MainView;
            await mainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
        else if (CurrentApplication.MainPage != null)
        {
            await CurrentApplication.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
    }

    public Task NavigateToAsync<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : ViewModelBase=> InternalNavigateToAsync(typeof(TViewModel), null);

    public Task NavigateToAsync<TViewModel>(object parameter) where TViewModel : ViewModelBase=> InternalNavigateToAsync(typeof(TViewModel), parameter);

    public Task NavigateToAsync(Type viewModelType) => InternalNavigateToAsync(viewModelType, null);

    public Task NavigateToAsync(Type viewModelType, object parameter) => InternalNavigateToAsync(viewModelType, parameter);

    public virtual Task RemoveLastFromBackStackAsync()
    {
        if (CurrentApplication.MainPage is MainView mainPage)
        {
            mainPage.Navigation.RemovePage(
                mainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[mainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2]);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    protected Page CreateAndBindPage(Type viewModelType, object parameter)
    {
        var pageType = GetPageTypeForViewModel(viewModelType);

        if (pageType == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Mapping type for {viewModelType} is not a page");
        }

        var page = Activator.CreateInstance(pageType) as Page;
        var viewModel = Locator.Instance.Resolve(viewModelType) as ViewModelBase;
        page.BindingContext = viewModel;

        return page;
    }

    void CreatePageViewModelMappings()
    {
        mappings.Add(typeof(SplashViewModel), typeof(SplashView));
        mappings.Add(typeof(LoginViewModel), typeof(LoginView));
        mappings.Add(typeof(MainViewModel), typeof(MainView));
        mappings.Add(typeof(Tab1ViewModel), typeof(Tab1View));
        mappings.Add(typeof(Tab2ViewModel), typeof(Tab2View));
        mappings.Add(typeof(Tab3ViewModel), typeof(Tab3View));
        mappings.Add(typeof(Tab4ViewModel), typeof(Tab4View));
    }
}
```

**MainView xaml:**

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            xmlns:page="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Views;assembly=SampleApp"
            x:Class="SampleApp.Views.MainView">

        <page:Tab1View Title="Tab1" Icon="tab1.png"/>
        <page:Tab2View Title="Tab2" Icon="tab2.png"/>
        <page:Tab3View Title="Tab3" Icon="tab3.png"/>
        <page:Tab4View Title="Tab4" Icon="tab4.png"/>

</TabbedPage>
```

**LoginViewModel:**

After successful login:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<MainViewModel>();
```

Comment: I know you posted this on the Autofac issues list, however, none of the Autofac maintainers are Xamarin or WPF folks, so hopefully someone in the community will be able to help.

Comment: Are none of the ViewModels being called, or are you facing the issue only for the Tapped Page viewmodels?

Comment: @Saamer Only Tabbed page's (Child page) view models didn't call, login view model gets called

Comment: I have faced the same issue now. Is anybody have an idea for this issue?

Comment: Hello! Have you found any solutions for using Autofac with TabbedPage? Facing same issue now :(

Comment: @neuromouse No buddy